# Sublime Text 3 - OS X Command Line, subl doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

sI cannot make alias 'sublime' to work suing

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

I checked path:

```
/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/
```

> $ls- la

total 0

> drwxr-xr-x  2 ks  admin   68 Jan 19 11:22 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x  3 ks  admin  102 Dec 16 21:25 ..

This is what I tired to do:

1. open file using subl
2. $ cd subl

> -bash: cd: subl: No such file or directory

1. $ open subl

> The file /Applications/Sublime
>   Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl does not exist.

1. $ subl --help

> -bash: subl: command not found

Comment: If the image content isn't there then something happened during the install; that's where `subl` is. In any case, this isn't programming-related.

Comment: Great, thanks! I just reinstalled Sublime Text, now subl file IS in the folder. After this fix I followed >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/sublime-text-3-subl-command  finally it works!

Answer (score 0):

If it is still isn't working after you created the symlink, the file might be quarantined. To check, open a terminal and get yourself to the directory that `subl` is in. Once you are there, check the extended permissions by typing:

`xatt subl`

If you see `com.apple.quarantine`, your file is quarantined. To remove the quarantine do ...

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine my_jar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Should do the trick. See this post for additional info [Sublime Text 3 and Terminal prompt for OS X Mavericks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543643/sublime-text-3-and-terminal-prompt-for-os-x-mavericks)

Answer (score -1):

few small things you can try

```
sudomkdir /usr/local

sudomkdir /usr/local/bin

sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sub
```

remember to change the sublime text version to that which you have installed ( I recommend 2/3, not the first one)

Usage in Terminal:

(for directory you're currently in) subl .

(any other directory) subl ~/Documents/example.txt

Try:

mkdir /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl

Comment: I have this directory but problem is with running subl, even from it's source path, where it is suppose to run from /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/. For instance '/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl . ' does not work.

Comment: 1. check that sublime text is within the applications folder

Comment: 2. open the contents and check for Contents/SharedSupport/bin ... etc

Comment: If they are not there, re-download and restart instructions

Comment: All the answers are in my post above :-) What else should I expect in Contents/SharedSupport/bin except what is listed?   (btw Sublime Text works from finder.)    In Applications I have sublime & Sublime Text.app

Comment: I just re-read your usage of "subl"... Please use it like this "edited answer"

Comment: I think you did not read question carefully but thank you for attempt to help :-)