# Command to open Sublime from OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext

Is there a way to open files using Sublime from OSX terminal:

Like this in Linux, but the equivalent in OSX:

```
gedit file.txt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 3 and Terminal prompt for OS X Mavericks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543643/sublime-text-3-and-terminal-prompt-for-os-x-mavericks)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also create a symbolic link to Sublime Text to launch it from the terminal with a simple command like "sublime *path*":

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

You should change the installation path accordingly. It's also possible to use any other alias than sublime, but it's best to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the general command for opening files with an application, like:

```
open -a Sublime.app file.txt
```

Comment: If the question is about application program  "Sublime Text", this would be the call for v. 2: `open -a Sublime\ Text\ 2.app file.txt`, probably likewise for v.3.

Comment: yes, it worked for me as `open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/ text.js `

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app
```

If you want to keep `sublime` as an alias for future use you can add it to your `.bash_profile`:

```
echo "alias subl=\"open /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app\"" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
sublime
```